# Fancybox modal starts to fail after subsequent ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I've a page that is suppose to display a fancybox modal with an image when a i user clicks on the list of links to the images.
I've this in my page being loaded

```
        $('a#couponLink').fancybox({
          'opacity'       : true,
          'overlayShow'   : false,
          'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
          'transitionOut' : 'none'
        });
```

Think Links:

```
<a href="images/<%= coupon.couponImageURL %>" id="couponLink" class="view">View Coupon ></a>
```

Now before I made the page dynamic with ajax, all worked.
But, I've added some ajax filters that process a index.js.erb file that filters the list of objects in the list. After firing off the ajax requests the above link fails to load a modal and just takes me to a page of the image, and not loading it in a modal?

Not sure what could be causing this or how to diagnose the issue? Any pointers to see why the fancybox is not firing?

One possibility I looked at was in my index.js.erb file, I do call

```
<% if session[:zip] and !(session[:zip].blank?) %>
$.fancybox.close();
 <% end %>
```

To close a particular modal that is suppose to load when a new user views the page and once we have some session parameters set, it is suppose to no longer show. These are two different fancybox modals on the same page with different classes. But is calling the close on the fancybox affecting the image modals?

Looking at the source after a ajax request, I still see all the appropriate libraries being loaded?

Reloading the page restores the fancybox functionality on the image links.
Odd, I know.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by:
1- Converting the links to classes instead of id's
2- Putting the fancybox code also into the .js.erb file.

Apperently when

```
    $('a.couponLink').fancybox({
    'opacity'       : true,
    'overlayShow'   : true,
    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'none'
    });
```

Gets run for the first time, it triggers a list of links that can be used to open a fancy box. Upon any form of ajax request elsewhere on the page, this list of links is negated somehow. So adding the above code again into the .js.erb file to be run after every ajax request, reregisters the links.